# Android Image captured force close

Tags: android, image, capture

When I capture an image from the camera then load it using

```
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

using HTC one it's working fine, but using large phones .. like S2
the app crashed ( fore close )

this is my camera function code

```
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            MpClick.start();
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

how to decode the image so it be smaller and dont fore close or scale the image ?

UPDATE ---

```
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
        }
    });
```

still it doesn't work .. anyone has other solutions to decrease image size so it don't force close

Comment: Please post the LogCat errors from the force close.

Comment: I can't, because you can't use your camera while you're connected to USB. but I think it's "dalvikvm: external allocation too large for this process"

Comment: this is not the right way to use inSampleSize, use it in onActivityResult part of your code

Comment: I do , but still it force close .. later I'll get the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all problem is an issue with Galaxy S2 phones ..

so there is no solve, but the app is working great on all other phones ..

thanks all